# Nginx server not available to the public

Tags: nginx

I thought this Nginx setup was supposed to be easy :( I can get my index.html to load on localhost only but when I try to access the site by my domain name it doesn't work, or even if I try the server IP address externally it doesn't resolve :( What am I doing wrong? The is on Windows. Here is my conf;

```
    #user  nobody;
    worker_processes  auto;

    events {
    worker_connections  2048;
    }


   http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  5;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
       listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

       #charset koi8-r;

       #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

       location / {
       #    root   html;
        root C:/xampp/htdocs;
           index  index.php index.html index.htm;
       }

       #error_page  404              /404.html;

       # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
       #
       error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
       location = /50x.html {
           root   html;
       }
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue was that I didn't enable Nginx in the Windows Firewall. Working now.